# $\Bbb C^n-\{z_1=0\}$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have done a problem that $\Bbb R^n-\{x_1=0\}$ has two connected components. This can be proved by using [Jordan–Brouwer separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem). However, to prove $\Bbb C^n-\{z_1=0\}$ is connected the theorem can work no longer. I don't know where even to begin.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\Bbb C^n\setminus \{z_1=0\}=\Bbb C^*\times \Bbb C^{n-1}$$

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit detail? I'm quite new to this area :( Is $\Bbb C^*=\Bbb C -\{0\}$? Then why $C^*$ and  $\Bbb C^{n-1}$ both are connected?

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb C^*=\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$. It is connected because it is pathwise connected: make a drawing! The space  $\Bbb C^{n-1}$ is connected because $\Bbb C$ is connected and a product of connected spaces is connected.

Answer (score 0):

You could produce a continuous bijection from $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb {R}^n $ to $\mathbb {C}^n $